# Alert videojs when ended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a video using the video.js lib which is awesome but I'm looking to get an alert out of it when it has ended because what I'm doing it checking that so it unlocks the next video but iv tried to seek a solution but it doesn't seem to be working as expected and wondering if somebody could cast an eye on it.

So my video id is `videoPlayerNew`

The script I'm using is:

```
var video = videojs('videoPlayerNew').ready(function(){
  var player = this;

  player.on('ended', function() {
    alert('video is done!');
  });
});
```

The error I'm getting in the console is: `video.php:98 Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined(…)`

Comment: did you include the video.js library before this function is called?

Comment: `videojs is not defined` make sure you load video.js before this script is loaded

Comment: Holy moly how dumb am I.

Comment: @Dan happens to the best ;), maybe good to close the question since it was something silly